# Copying error in file system of hdfs

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I wrote the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin
./hadoop namenode -format
./start-all.sh
./hadoop fs -rmr hdfs://192.168.1.8:7000/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/output
./hadoop fs -rmr hdfs://192.168.1.8:7000/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input
./hadoop fs -mkdir hdfs://192.168.1.8:7000/export/hadoop-1.0.1/input
./readwritepaths
./hadoop fs -put /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt hdfs://192.168.1.8:7000/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt
./hadoop jar /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/ParallelIndexation.jar org.myorg.ParallelIndexation /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/output -D mapred.map.tasks=1 1> resultofexecute.txt 2>&1
```

As a result of its execution on a command

```
./hadoop fs -put /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt hdfs://192.168.1.8:7000/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt
```

I received the following messages

```
13/04/28 10:13:15 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1066)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at $Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
    at $Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3507)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2700(DFSClient.java:2586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2826)

13/04/28 10:13:15 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block null bad datanode[0] nodes == null
13/04/28 10:13:15 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt" - Aborting...
put: java.io.IOException: File /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
13/04/28 10:13:15 ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Exception closing file /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt : org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1066)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at $Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
    at $Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3507)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2700(DFSClient.java:2586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2826)
```

I give also datanode a log on one of the subordinate nodes (on the second subordinate node this log contains a similar error)

```
2013-04-28 11:10:40,634 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = myhost2/192.168.1.10
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1243785; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Tue Feb 14 08:15:38 UTC 2012
************************************************************/
2013-04-28 11:10:40,948 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-04-28 11:10:40,982 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-04-28 11:10:40,983 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:40,983 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2013-04-28 11:10:41,285 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-04-28 11:10:41,308 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-04-28 11:10:42,811 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 0 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:43,811 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 1 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:44,813 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 2 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:45,814 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 3 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:46,814 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 4 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:47,814 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 5 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:48,815 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 6 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:49,815 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 7 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:50,816 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 8 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:51,818 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 9 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:51,822 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC: Server at 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000 not available yet, Zzzzz...
2013-04-28 11:10:53,824 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 0 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:54,825 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 1 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:55,826 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 2 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:56,828 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 3 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:57,828 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 4 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:58,829 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 5 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:10:59,829 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 6 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:11:00,830 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 7 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:11:01,831 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 8 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:11:02,831 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 9 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:11:02,833 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC: Server at 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000 not available yet, Zzzzz...
2013-04-28 11:11:04,834 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 0 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:11:05,834 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 1 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:11:06,835 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 2 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:11:07,836 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 3 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:11:08,837 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 4 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:11:09,837 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7000. Already tried 5 time(s).
2013-04-28 11:11:40,381 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Incompatible namespaceIDs in /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/data: namenode namespaceID = 454531810; datanode namespaceID = 345408440
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.doTransition(DataStorage.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1665)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1682)

2013-04-28 11:11:40,383 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at myhost2/192.168.1.10
************************************************************/
```

Help to eliminate a copying error. @ChrisWhite namenode log.

```
2013-04-28 10:10:38,310 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = one/192.168.1.8
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1243785; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Tue Feb 14 08:15:38 UTC 2012
************************************************************/
2013-04-28 10:10:38,579 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-04-28 10:10:38,594 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-04-28 10:10:38,596 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-04-28 10:10:38,596 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2013-04-28 10:11:08,818 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-04-28 10:11:08,825 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-04-28 10:11:08,831 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2013-04-28 10:11:08,832 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered.
2013-04-28 10:11:08,852 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit
2013-04-28 10:11:08,854 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2% max memory = 19.33375 MB
2013-04-28 10:11:08,854 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^22 = 4194304 entries
2013-04-28 10:11:08,855 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=4194304, actual=4194304
2013-04-28 10:11:08,977 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=hadoop
2013-04-28 10:11:08,977 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
2013-04-28 10:11:08,977 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
2013-04-28 10:11:08,983 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
2013-04-28 10:11:08,983 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2013-04-28 10:11:09,088 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean
2013-04-28 10:11:09,129 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
2013-04-28 10:11:09,143 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Number of files = 1
2013-04-28 10:11:09,147 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Number of files under construction = 0
2013-04-28 10:11:09,147 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file of size 112 loaded in 0 seconds.
2013-04-28 10:11:09,147 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Edits file /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/name/current/edits of size 4 edits # 0 loaded in 0 seconds.
2013-04-28 10:11:09,149 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file of size 112 saved in 0 seconds.
2013-04-28 10:11:09,157 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file of size 112 saved in 0 seconds.
2013-04-28 10:11:09,160 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameCache: initialized with 0 entries 0 lookups
2013-04-28 10:11:09,160 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Finished loading FSImage in 192 msecs
2013-04-28 10:11:09,176 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Total number of blocks = 0
2013-04-28 10:11:09,177 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of invalid blocks = 0
2013-04-28 10:11:09,177 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of under-replicated blocks = 0
2013-04-28 10:11:09,177 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of  over-replicated blocks = 0
2013-04-28 10:11:09,177 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Safe mode termination scan for invalid, over- and under-replicated blocks completed in 15 msec
2013-04-28 10:11:09,177 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Leaving safe mode after 0 secs.
2013-04-28 10:11:09,177 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Network topology has 0 racks and 0 datanodes
2013-04-28 10:11:09,177 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* UnderReplicatedBlocks has 0 blocks
2013-04-28 10:11:09,192 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.HostsFileReader: Refreshing hosts (include/exclude) list
2013-04-28 10:11:09,204 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source FSNamesystemMetrics registered.
2013-04-28 10:11:09,223 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcDetailedActivityForPort7000 registered.
2013-04-28 10:11:09,223 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcActivityForPort7000 registered.
2013-04-28 10:11:09,225 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Namenode up at: one/192.168.1.8:7000
2013-04-28 10:11:09,245 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting SocketReader
2013-04-28 10:11:09,247 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: First cycle completed 0 blocks in 0 msec
2013-04-28 10:11:09,247 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: Queue flush completed 0 blocks in 0 msec processing time, 0 msec clock time, 1 cycles
2013-04-28 10:11:09,248 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: InvalidateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: First cycle completed 0 blocks in 0 msec
2013-04-28 10:11:09,248 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: InvalidateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: Queue flush completed 0 blocks in 0 msec processing time, 0 msec clock time, 1 cycles
2013-04-28 10:11:39,379 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2013-04-28 10:11:39,559 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
2013-04-28 10:11:39,574 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: dfs.webhdfs.enabled = false
2013-04-28 10:11:39,582 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50070
2013-04-28 10:11:39,583 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 50070 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 50070
2013-04-28 10:11:39,583 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 50070
2013-04-28 10:11:39,583 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2013-04-28 10:11:40,093 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50070
2013-04-28 10:11:40,093 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Web-server up at: 0.0.0.0:50070
2013-04-28 10:11:40,111 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2013-04-28 10:11:40,170 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 9 on 7000: starting
2013-04-28 10:11:40,171 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 8 on 7000: starting
2013-04-28 10:11:40,171 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 7 on 7000: starting
2013-04-28 10:11:40,171 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 6 on 7000: starting
2013-04-28 10:11:40,171 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 5 on 7000: starting
2013-04-28 10:11:40,171 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 4 on 7000: starting
2013-04-28 10:11:40,171 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 3 on 7000: starting
2013-04-28 10:11:40,172 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 7000: starting
2013-04-28 10:11:40,172 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 7000: starting
2013-04-28 10:11:40,172 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 7000: starting
2013-04-28 10:11:40,172 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 7000: starting
2013-04-28 10:11:41,177 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hadoop cause:java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
2013-04-28 10:11:41,180 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 7000, call addBlock(/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info, DFSClient_1259183364, null) from 192.168.1.8:37770: error: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)
```

Comment: Looks like data node is failing to register with name node - can you share the name node logs too?

Comment: @ChrisWhite I added a required log.

Comment: What are the values of the following in your hdfs-site.xml: `dfs.name.dir`, `dfs.data.dir`?

Comment: @ChrisWhite Dfs.name.dir and dfs.data.dir values in the hdfs-site.xml file aren't set. With what they shall be?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the values of dfs.name.dir and dfs.data.dir properties in your hdfs-site.xml otherwise they will most probably default to the temporary directory (which as @rVr notes in his answer gets wiped at system restart).

As for suitable values - it depends on your system, but typically you should create a directory for the dfs.name.dir (on your name node server) and then another directory for the dfs.data.dir (or in most production cluster, this is a csv values of directories on different disks).

Once you've created and configured these values, you'll need to make sure the hdfs-site.xml file is distributed across your cluster. After which you should re-format your namenode and finally start up your HDFS services using the scripts in the bin folder (be sure to run this script from the machine where your name node runs)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the cause is either the data nodes are not running, or the dfs.data.dir is configured on the tmp directory, which is cleared when machine restart.Can you include a jps command before put to make sure datanode is running and test if you can passwordless ssh between namenode and datanode. Also a firewall between nodes can be causing this problem.